# Would google index our page if we have it in sitemap but do not have any links for that on website?

Tags: seo, sitemap, links

**Short**

Would google index my web-page if it's not on my website but it's in the sitemap?

**Long**

We have a few product price pages i.e. for product bwm-x3, following are 3 URLs:

```
-> bmw-x3-price-in-city1
-> bmw-x3-price-in-city2
-> bmw-x3-price-in-city3
```

We have a link on our website to these pages if the price of bmw-x3 is available in the respective city.

Now, we are planning to also create pages for cities where we don't have prices but we have prices in nearby cities but we don't want to link these pages from website. Although, we want users to land on this page from google.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all URLs on the sitemap are crawled by google bot but it does not guarantee indexation.

Yes, it would be eligible for getting indexed but you can't be 100% sure if it will be indexed.

This will happen irrespective of the presence of the links to those pages on your website.

If Google deems your pages unworthy due to a large number ‘low quality’ or duplicate content, they might not be indexed.